# How to show part of text in datagrid row details?

Tags: wpfdatagrid

I have table in my database which has fields of ID,NAME,CONTEXT. I am showing search result in datagrid. Now I tried to do this

```
        <WpfToolkit:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                **<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="CadetBlue" FontSize="13" 
                            Width="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Text="{Binding Path=Context}"/>
                    </StackPanel>**
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </WpfToolkit:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

It is giving whole text which is not what I want. If you give me some directions how to do this, may be some code. It will be appreciated. I want to show only that part of text which is selected by this line of code.

```
 private void Find_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
             cmdSel = new SqlCommand();
             cmdSel.Connection = MainWindow.conn;

               cmdSel.CommandText = "select id,Name,Context from document where Contains([Context],'FormsOf (INFLECTIONAL, \"" + TextBoxSearch.Text + "\")')";

                     da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSel);
             da.Fill(ds, "MainSearchBinding");
             resWin.DataGrid1.DataContext = ds;

                   }
```

For example you are searching for "audio" and it is showing 10 words before + "audio" + 10 word after audio. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add one more column "Intro" to my table.

```
 <WpfToolkit:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5" >
                            <TextBlock Foreground="CadetBlue" FontSize="13" 
                            Width="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                            Text="{Binding Path=Intro}"/>

                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </WpfToolkit:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

And wrote this code for mouse click.

```
private void OnMouseClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

            IList rows = DataGrid1.SelectedItems;
            DataRowView row = (DataRowView)DataGrid1.SelectedItems[0];
            int a = (int)row["ID"];
            string t = (string)row["Context"]; //getting all text from Context
            string srch1 = UCSearch.srch; // search box text

            if (t.IndexOf(srch1) != -1)
            {
                string retString = t.Substring(t.IndexOf(srch1), 100); //cutting from occured text and more 100 symbols

                row["Intro"] = retString; // setting to Intro Column 

            }


        }
```

I hope some one may need it. Thank you.